# Hide application link from Facebook share (on page tabs)

Tags: facebook, tabs, share

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible to remove or change application link from feed post when sharing a page tab ("XX minutes ago from *[app name]*" next to comment and like links where *[app name]* is a link to the application). But the application in question only provides a custom page tab, not a real application, so it's kind of annoying when users are pointed to the app page.

I'm using **FB.ui** share the page tab.

Or maybe someone has alternate solution to make the user experience better?

Here's the share code (with some modifications since the app isn't public yet :)

```
    FB.ui({
method: 'feed',
name: 'name of the page tab',
picture: 'http://url/to/image.png',
link: 'http://url/to/page/tab',
caption: 'caption',
message: 'message',
description: 'description',
actions: [
    {
    name: 'Participate',
    link: 'http://url/to/page/tab'
    }
]
}, shareComplete);
```

Comment: Where would you like the link to take users then?

Comment: no u cant do that.If u are sharing via apps..XX minutes ago from [app name] will appear

Comment: Nitzan Tomer: Preferably to the page tab. I don't know why users would want to end up on an application page that does nothing. I guess I could create a "dummy app" that would point users to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

*edit: just saw that the question was two years ago, oh well, I'll just leave this here for future reference :P

What I did was create a redirect.php on my server that just does a redirect to the page tab I want:

```
<?php

header('Location: PAGE_TAB_URL');

exit();

?>
```

then, on tha facebook app, I added a website as a new platform and enetred the redirect.php url as the the site url.

Now, on the share ui, when the user clicks on the app name it redirects them to the page tab. Only downside that the redirect url is visible on mouseovering the link but I can live with that.